# Simple PHP but need to click button twice for working

Tags: php, wordpress, post

I just make it simple request to delete data from my post. Firstly I use wordpress but I make custom code use PHP.

Second, this is just simple form PHP when button click trigger an action, but in this case I need to click twice for make it work.

Here my code. I am just beginner and still learn.
I use UIkit for styling my button.

```
 <?php
        $posttags = get_the_tags();
                        if ($posttags) {
                            foreach($posttags as $tag) {
                                    $tag_name = $tag->name;

            echo '<form method="POST">';
            echo '<span class="uk-button-group">';
                    echo ' <button class="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-button-small" disabled style="background-color: #008CBA;" name="' .$tag->term_id . '">' . $tag->name . '</button>';
                    echo ' <input type="hidden" name="tagit" value="'.$tag->name .'" >';
                    echo ' <button type="submit" name="submit" class="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-button-small">x</button>';
            echo '</span>&nbsp;';
            echo '</form>';
            if (isset($_POST['submit']) || isset($_POST['tagit'])){

                    foreach((array)$_POST['tagit'] as $tag){
                wp_remove_object_terms( get_the_id(), $tag, 'post_tag' );

                    }
            }
            }}?>
```

Please teach me where I make it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the code block beginning with

> ```
>   if (isset($_POST['submit']) || isset($_POST['tagit'])){
> ```

nearer to  the top.
You seem to be deleting the old info only after you read it.